# What is this grub-like bug that's eating my eggplant leaves?

Tags: identification, pests, bugs, eggplant

Recently I noticed some bugs eating the leaves of my eggplant. This is the first time I've ever seen these and so far the only plants they are on are the eggplant, they wont touch the peppers next to them. They look almost like short grubs and seem to stay along the edges of the leaves.

[image: image 1]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like [false potato beetle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_potato_beetle) larva.

See a [google search](https://www.google.bg/search?q=false+potato+beetle+larvae+images) for images of the larvae.

You are lucky, as these are described as "not serious pest". However, if I was in your place, I would gather and dispose of them.